# Setting formula range from first to last populated cell in a column?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, array-formulas

For a league I run we keep track of games played and w/l/t and calculate that into a ranking score.  The player name is listed in column U and the ranking score in column AD of a fixed table.  I then use an array formula to list the players in ranking order in column E (then vlookup to pull in other stats based on the value in E for that row).  Specifically I use this formula in column E:

`=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX($U$4:$U$153,MATCH(LARGE($AD$4:$AD$153-ROW($AD$4:$AD$153)/COUNT($AD$4:$AD$153),ROW(E72)-ROW(E$4)+1),$AD$4:$AD$153-ROW($AD$4:$AD$153)/COUNT($AD$4:$AD$153),0))), 1, 1)`

I need to be able to add players to the table in U:AD without having to edit the formula every time, i.e. from $U4:$U153 and $AD$4:$AD$153 to $U4:$U154 and $AD$4:$AD$154 in all the various places in the formula then copy the new formula all the way down.

Is there a way that I could define the range as $U$4:$U(last populated row) and the same for column AD in the above formula?

I eventually be using this in both Excel and Google Sheets so I would really like to avoid scripting. First I'm looking to solve this for Google Sheets.

[Here is a copy of the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CopCzSR7PaU6CZFBXEzocrIYy3CytklnTvuWTyhaxXk/edit?usp=sharing) I am working on.

Comment: You can use $U4:$U in Google sheets but not in excel.  In excel you can format your data as a table and that will copy down formulas and number formats when you add new rows. You don't need to use an array formula in excel.

Comment: I need the solution most for google sheets at the moment.  Won't using $U$4:$U include all the blank rows below the last populated row?  This would then place players with a negative rank (more losses than wins by my ranking formula that was not posted - column AD is a number that is positive for winning record, zero, or negative for losing record) below any blank rows that would be counted as zero, if I'm thinking correctly.

I hadn't thought of the table solution for excel but I think that would probably take care of the excel side.

Comment: It will put the formula result into the blank rows so you'll need an if statement something like `if(IS BLANK($A$4:$A`),"",<your formula>)`.  This is normal in Google sheets array formulas to check if there are values for the formula to work with.

Comment: I just tested the $U4:$U method, and it works great except for the negative number aspect mentioned in my previous comment.  For reference, I've added a link to the google sheet as it stands for anyone to view.

Comment: Sorry. Just realised that you formula has a count using the range so that may need to also be changed to a countif.  Another approach could be to use a count to create a range that you could use the INDIRECT function with in your formula.

Comment: I considered the ISBLANK when just testing the $U$4:$U method but couldn't quite get my brain around making it fit in there correctly.  Maybe I just need more coffee.

Comment: ARRAY_CONSTRAIN and ARRAYFORMULA functions only works on Google Sheets, not on Excel. The OP mentioned that they need the "solution most for Google Sheets for the moment", so I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, Rubén.  The formula I have in Excel is the same except without the `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA ...)` and just starts with `{=INDEX ... }`.  But yes, the google sheet is the one that will be public so that is the one I need to get working first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for the Google sheet that you shared.

*skip to the end for the simple solution*

I used the indirect method by entering a formula in `E1` that counts the AD column for player stats and adds 3 to get the last row. (I was going create the full range *AD4:AD??* but you also have *U4:U73* in the formula)

`=counta(AD4:AD)+3`

I then changed your formula use *indirect*, `indirect("$AD$4:AD"&E$1)`, to reference the last row number in cell E1 to create the required range.

`=iferror(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(indirect("$U$4:U"&E$1),MATCH(LARGE(indirect("$AD$4:AD"&E$1)-ROW(indirect("$AD$4:AD"&E$1))/COUNT(indirect("$AD$4:$AD"&E$1)),ROW(E4)-ROW(E$4)+1),indirect("$AD$4:$AD"&E$1)-ROW(indirect("$AD$4:$AD"&E$1))/COUNT(indirect("$AD$4:AD"&E$1)),0))), 1, 1),"")`

I discovered by accident that if you remove the *ARRAY_CONSTRAIN* from your formula and change *U4:U73* to *U4:**AC**73* then the formula will populate the scores to the right of your formula where you currently have *vlookups*.  I put an example of this in E4 but note that you will have to delete the vlookup formulas if you want to fill the formula down otherwise it will show *REF*

I also added *iferror* so that the formula can be copied to the same row as the end of the "open slots" in column A without showing errors.

Also, I got to this point and was thinking that since you're using Google Sheets, a better way to do this could be to use the **QUERY** function to pull the data and also sort it using *ORDER BY* with a single formula in cell E4.

I've not really used the QUERY function but maybe it's time to learn.

**EDIT**

Turns out it doesn't take much learning

`=QUERY(U4:AD,"SELECT U,V,W,X,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC ORDER BY AD DESC")`

Put the formula above in cell E4 and delete everything beneath and scores to the right and you're done.  you'll notice that there is no indirect because Google understands that you don't want the blank rows.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16IclEmKwDFdInIAZhH2vt-tLJ5pbwX06jv9xrUXwhnY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: THIS.  I didn't even know `=QUERY` was a thing.  This is more than I was looking for and solves more than just this issue.  

I've never used the INDIRECT and didn't have a chance since you first suggested it to look into it.  I've looked at it now and that is a nice solution that would have done the job nicely, but I'm using your QUERY solution instead.  THANKS for the help.  Marked this as the answer.

Comment: Incidentally, `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA` are added by google docs when pasting an `{INDEX ... }` from Excel.  I wasn't sure about them, though I've used ARRAYFORMULA before, and it did what it was supposed to, until now, so I had just left them there.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `INDEX` and `COUNTA`

Instead of `$U4$U153`,

```
$U4:INDEX(U4:U,COUNTA(A4:A))
```

The `COUNTA` portion will give the number of populated rows and feed  it into `INDEX` to give `$U4:$U153`

Comment: Add `$` signs as needed.

Comment: If @Gordon hadn't posted his solution, I think I probably would have been working with this.  Thanks.

Comment: @PoundCake I did not suggest `QUERY`, because you wanted a excel compatible solution. Also, I avoided `INDIRECT`  because it's volatile. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using $ signs around U4:U153,remove $ signs for rows that will give you flexibility while keeping columns fixed.As your drag the formula,the data array will append the newly filled cells or you can create table using Ctrl+T that will automatically expand as you keeping adding data.

Comment: The $ keep the range constant when dragging.  For example in column E where the formula is, if E1 had the range as U4:U153 and I dragged that formula down to row 10, the formula in row 10 would have the range of U13:U162 which completely defeats the purpose of the formula.

I understand why you suggested this, I could freeze the start at $U$4 and have the end point dynamic if I just drag the bottom row, but that creates the problem of having a different range for different rows in column E.  That won't work because column E is sorting all players in column U by rank in column AD.